# Как избежать замусоривания cron'ом директория root?

Tags: cron

Пользовательский crontab `/var/cron/tabs/root` выполняет php-скрипты через wget-запросы с отключёнными уведомлениями (`>/dev/null 2>&1`). При этом в папке `/root` создаются пустые (0 байт) файлы с именами скриптов. Имена файлов дополняются номером в виде расширения: `script.php`, `script.php.1`, `script.php.2` и т.д. Спустя несколько месяцев в `/root` появляются десятки тысяч ненужных файлов. Что можно сделать, чтобы такого не было?

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос решился с помощью опций -q и -v wget'а. Прошу извинить за беспокойство.

P.S. wget -q -v остановил запись в /root, но перестал выполнять скрипты. Окончательно помогла опция --delete-after - скрипты срабатывают, не оставляя следов.

Comment: вам спасибо,-грабли)

Answer (score 0):

`--delete-after` - плохой вариант, так как запись на диск всё равно производится: сначала файл создаётся, потом удаляется. Получается лишняя, абсолютно ненужная дисковая активность и замедление работы.

Если Вы хотите, чтобы файлы вовсе не создавались, проще их не создавать! В этом поможет опция `-O`:

```
    -O file
    --output-document=file
The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all will
be concatenated together and written to file.  If - is used as file,
documents will be printed to standard output, disabling
link conversion.  (Use ./- to print to a file literally named -.)
```

Итого команда, скачивающая файл, но не сохраняющая его на диск и не выводящая ничего в стандартные потоки, будет выглядеть так:

```
wget http://example.com/file.txt -O /dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1
```